# How to analysis this ROC curve and improve the performance?

Tags: classification, roc, unbalanced-classes

There are 3 classes with imbalanced number of training samples. I've got the following classification metrics:

[image: accuracy]

and the following ROC curve on the validation set:

[image: roc]

As shown in the confusion matrix on validation set, it seems all the samples of `Class 2` are wrongly classified. But from the ROC curve, it seems to some extent the `Class 2` are good classified with a reasonable threshold.

My question is, how to improve the classification performance on `Class 2`? Any comments are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How to improve the performance is model specific. ROC only gives you feedback on your model.

Comment: @StudentT, thanks for comments! Is this a valid ROC curve, along with the confusion matrix? From the confusion matrix, the `Class 2` are all mis-classified.

Answer (score 0):

try to add class weights when computing your loss function derived from your label distribution. That way you will give more emphasis on labels that are misrepresented in your dataset due to low frequency.
here are some other methods as well: https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/ 
But there are plenty of forma papers as well.

Comment: Could you cite/link at least one such paper? – *Reviewer*

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your kind answers and suggestions!

Comment: do not know by heart, google is your best friend. I had the same issue and I used Keras class weights. Can't recall sources